# mobclix does not show any ads,failed to load ads with errorcode 503 and 999999

Tags: android, ads, mobclix

I am developing android application in which i want to use Mobclix to serve ads.
I have download the Mobclix SDK along with its sample project.
I have replace the App_Id in sample project with my App_Id but it does not show any ads(not even test ads ).
When i look at my Logcat i see following are the concern:

The ad request failed with `error code: -999999`

OR

The ad request failed with `error code: -503`

OR

The ad request failed with `error code: -777777`

what does it mean?
how can i solve this?

**Note:** 1) I have setup the application on Mobclix server as per the guide provided by Mobclix 
2) I want to show Banner ads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look the documentation (sdk.html) included with the Mobclix SDK for the error code descriptions:

```
-503    // Advertisement is not available at this time.
-777777 // Ad did not display because the app is not in the foreground.
-999999 // Ad size has been disabled on the Mobclix Developer Dashboard.
```